# Flask - Insertar imágenes con jinja2

Tags: python, flask

Estoy creando un CRUD, en el cual utilizo flask para el backend  y empleo el motor de platillas jinja2 para cargar los datos en el frontend. Coma tal, la app es una galería, al momento de cargar los datos, lo realizo con un bucle "for", con el cual, deseo establecer la ruta o "path" de la imagen en el atributo "src" de la etiqueta . Me gustaría saber como realizarlo de forma correcta para pintar la imagen en pantalla.

Los datos los obtengo desde mongoDB

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<div>
    {% for doc in data %}
    <h2>{{doc.name}}</h2>
    <h2>{{doc._id}}</h2>
    <img src="{{ doc.image_path }}" alt="">
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: como lo guardas en la BD?, donde se ubican las imágenes?

Comment: En sí, las imágenes se almacenan en un fichero del proyecto, y en mongoDB se guarda la ruta de la imagen "image_path"

Comment: un ejemplo de lo que contendría `doc.image_path`??

Comment: C:\Users\user\Documents\Python_Proyects\python-gallery-crud\static\images\NZXT.jpg

Comment: ok, eso esta totalmente mal

Comment: Muy bien, ¿Una solución?

Comment: Estoy escribiendo una, pero... una pregunta, si visualizas la imagen? tienes algún problema en específico?

Comment: No, no es posible visualizarla, como tal se pinta en pantalla el nombre y el id, pero no la imagen

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128636/discussion-between-christian-and-joshua-rivera).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema principal es la forma en que guardas la imagen en la Base de Datos, aquí no debes de guardar toda la ruta solo debes guardar el nombre de la imagen (junto con su extensión) y esto por la sencilla razón de que, al momento que mandes tu aplicación a producción se romperá (igual si mueves tu proyecto a otra ruta) ya que tal ruta no existirá. Si solo guardamos el nombre de la imagen, entonces podemos usar la ruta relativa para entrar a la carpeta donde se guardan las imágenes.

Una vez que cambies la forma en que guardas las imágenes, entonces tendremos que mostrarlas de esta forma

```py
<div>
    {% for doc in data %}
    <h2>{{doc.name}}</h2>
    <h2>{{doc._id}}</h2>
    <img src="./static/imagenes/{{ doc.image_path }}" alt="">
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Recordemos que Flask renderizará todo lo que este en la carpeta `static` por lo que la ruta también cambiaría y por ende la forma en acceder a ella.

Un dato extra que te doy es que también puedes guardar las imágenes en la BD (no el nombre), esto se logra con el tipo de dato `blob`.

Comment: Excelente solución, en cuanto enviar una imagen como tipo de dato blob, ¿cómo lo realizaría con Flask?, conozco que para Node Js se utiliza "GridFS". Muchas gracias

Comment: tendrías que subir la imagen al servidor y transformarla a bytes para luego insertarla en tu BD cuyo campo debe estar como tipo blob, si tienes más dudas a cerca de esto recomiendo que hagas otra pregunta, ya que esto se aleja al tema de esta pregunta.